# How to process calls to a function one at a time?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger

There is an API call that executes a function that does something asynchronously and returns a Promise ( I am using async/await to wait for this result)

If there is another API call to the same function before it's execution, there is an error and the request fails. I could always write retry logic but I want to somehow make the other function calls wait until this promise from the first call is resolved.

How could I achieve that?

Update: Adding code (sample code)
This is a blockchain code, but what I want to make sure is just from the NodeJS side, how can i make function *invokeQueue* process requests one by one

API:

```
app.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
    var channel = hfc.getChannel();
    var eventHub = channel.newChannelEventHub(hfc.getPeer("org-service-peer1"))
    var peername = "org-service-peer1"
    var peerB = hfc.getPeer("org-service-peer1")
    let tx_id = await invokeccQueue(channel, peerB, eventHub, { chaincodeId: "cca", fcn: "move", args: [req.body.a, req.body.b, req.body.num] }, channel.getOrderer("orderer-service"))
    let tx_id1 = await invokeccQueue(channel, peerB, eventHub, { chaincodeId: "cca1", fcn: "move", args: [req.body.a, req.body.b, req.body.num] }, channel.getOrderer("orderer-service"))
    let tx_id2 = await invokeccQueue(channel, peerB, eventHub, { chaincodeId: "cca2", fcn: "move", args: [req.body.a, req.body.b, req.body.num] }, channel.getOrderer("orderer-service"))
    let tx_id3 = await invokeccQueue(channel, peerB, eventHub, { chaincodeId: "cca3", fcn: "move", args: [req.body.a, req.body.b, req.body.num] }, channel.getOrderer("orderer-service"))
    let tx_id4 = await invokeccQueue(channel, peerB, eventHub, { chaincodeId: "cca4", fcn: "move", args: [req.body.a, req.body.b, req.body.num] }, channel.getOrderer("orderer-service"))
    if (tx_id && tx_id1 && tx_id2 && tx_id3 && tx_id4)
        res.send(true)
    else
        res.send(false)
    // })

})
```

Function Call:

```
var invokeccQueue = async function (channel, peers, eventHubs, { chaincodeId, fcn, args }, transient) {
    console.log("Count is inside queue " + count)
    const client = channel._clientContext;
    var tx_id = client.newTransactionID();
    var tx_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID();
    var request;
    transient = JSON.stringify(transient)
    transient = new Buffer(transient).toString('base64')
    var pvt;
    console.log("chaincode id is " + chaincodeId)
    console.log("Function is " + fcn)

    request = {
        chaincodeId: chaincodeId,
        fcn: fcn,
        args: args,
        chainId: 'mychannel',
        txId: tx_id,
        targets: peers
    };

    try {
        let results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
        var proposalResponses = results[0];
        var proposal = results[1];
        var all_good = true;
        for (var i in proposalResponses) {
            let one_good = false;
            if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[i].response &&
                proposalResponses[i].response.status === 200) {
                one_good = true;
                logger.info('invoke chaincode proposal was good');
            } else {
                logger.info('invoke chaincode proposal was bad');
            }
            all_good = all_good & one_good;
        }

        if (all_good) {
            logger.info(util.format(
                'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s", metadata - "%s", endorsement signature: %s',
                proposalResponses[0].response.status, proposalResponses[0].response.message,
                proposalResponses[0].response.payload, proposalResponses[0].endorsement.signature));
            var promises = [];
            let event_hubs = channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg();
            console.log("Event hubs" + event_hubs)
            event_hubs.forEach((eh) => {
                logger.debug('invokeEventPromise - setting up event');
                let invokeEventPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let event_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                        let message = 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT:' + eh.getPeerAddr();
                        logger.info(message);
                        eh.disconnect();
                    }, 100000);
                    eh.registerTxEvent(tx_id_string, (tx, code, block_num) => {
                        logger.info('The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer %s', eh.getPeerAddr());
                        logger.info('Transaction %s has status of %s in blocl %s', tx, code, block_num);
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);

                        if (code !== 'VALID') {
                            let message = util.format('The invoke chaincode transaction was invalid, code:%s', code);
                            logger.info(message);
                            reject(new Error(message));
                        } else {
                            let message = 'The invoke chaincode transaction was valid.';
                            logger.info(message);
                            resolve(message);
                        }
                    }, (err) => {
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);
                        logger.info(err);
                        reject(err);
                    },
                        { unregister: true, disconnect: true }
                    );
                    eh.connect();
                });
                promises.push(invokeEventPromise);
            });

            var orderer_request = {
                txId: tx_id,
                proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
                proposal: proposal
            };
            var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(orderer_request, 10000);

            var error_message = "";
            var org_name = channel.getOrganizations();
            var channelName = "mychannel"
            promises.push(sendPromise);
            let results = await Promise.all(promises);
            logger.debug(util.format('------->>> R E S P O N S E : %j', results));
            let response = results.pop();
            if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                logger.info('Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.');
            } else {
                error_message = util.format('Failed to order the transaction. Error code: %s', response.status);
                logger.debug(error_message);
            }
            for (let i in results) {
                let event_hub_result = results[i];
                let event_hub = event_hubs[i];
                logger.debug('Event results for event hub :%s', event_hub.getPeerAddr());
                if (typeof event_hub_result === 'string') {
                    logger.debug(event_hub_result);
                } else {
                    if (!error_message) error_message = event_hub_result.toString();
                    logger.debug(event_hub_result.toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            error_message = util.format('Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse');
            logger.debug(error_message);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.info('Failed to invoke due to error: ' + error.stack ? error.stack : error);
        error_message = error.toString();
    }

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if (!error_message) {
            let message = util.format(
                'Successfully invoked the chaincode %s to the channel \'%s\' for transaction ID: %s',
                org_name, channelName, tx_id_string);
            logger.info(message);

            resolve(true);
        } else {
            let message = util.format('Failed to invoke chaincode. cause:%s', error_message);
            logger.info(message);
            resolve(false)
        }
    })



};
```

Comment: Show us your actual code and we can much more easily make a specific suggestion that will solve your issue in the exact context of your own code.  Answering generic questions without seeing your actual code is a lot harder and often requires guessing about all the little things you haven't included in your question that your actual code will show us.

Comment: Have you tried [npm:p-series](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-series)?

Comment: @jfriend00 the code has been added, it is blockchain code hence refrained so that it does not get confused as i just want answer that how can i control function calls in a way only one control is given at a time

Comment: @Paul no i havent, will check

Answer (score 0):

Have calls to the function always chain off of the Promise created on the previous call to it, with `.then`. The function will need a persistent variable to keep track of the last Promise created (which was done during the last call of the function). For example:

```js
const getApi = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'done'));
const fn = (() => {
  let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
  return () => {
    lastProm = lastProm.then(getApi);
    return lastProm;
  };
})();

fn().then(console.log);
fn().then(console.log);
fn().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a rate limiter to a function. Use bottleneck for this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out exactly where you think you have a problem with one-at-a-time API  calls.

Your code is not serialized in the `event_hubs.forEach()` loop.  There you are purposely accumulating an array of promises which allows all the `eh.registerTxEvent()` calls to be in-flight at the same time.  If you mean for that to be serialized, then you can use a regular `for` loop, wrap the `eh.registerTxEvent()` into a function that returns a promise and use `await` on that promise in the `for` loop.  That will serialize those calls.

Also, a function such as `eh.connect()` seems like it might be asynchronous and need proper async control around it.

Other questions about code we don't have any idea about.  Do these functions all return a promise that is properly resolved when their asynchronous operation is done?

```
channel.sendTransactionProposal()
channel.sendTransaction()
```

Other comments.  At the end of `invokeccQueue()`, you don't need to manufacture a resolved or rejected promise.  You can just return a value or throw an exception.  You're inside an `async` function body so returning a value automatically becomes the resolved value of the returned promise.  And, throwing an exception automatically becomes the reason for a rejected promise that it returns.  You don't need to manufacture your own promise.

Also in `invokeccQueue()`, you have a `setTimeout()` that when it fires, it doesn't do anything but log and disconnect.  It doesn't do anything to the parent promise which seems like a coding error.  You get a timeout, but don't actually change anything for how the function flows which seems like it's likely a mistake.

Inside `invokeccQueue()`, you are using a mix of `await`, manually constructed promises and regular callbacks.  That makes the code very, very hard to write, maintain and follow.  It's a ton easier to code if you abstract all callbacks and all manually created promises into functions that return promises.  Then, you can just use `await` on everything async and assure serial flow of control.

---

If this doesn't shine enough light on your actual problem, then please provide more details about exactly where in `invokeccQueue()` you're experiencing a problem?

Comment: Yes, `channel.sendTransactionProposal() and sendTransaction()` returns promises. I did not understand your point on `eh.connect()` and I am using the timeout to wait for the given time, if no response, I want to close the eventhub and say that the transaction failed/timed out.